# Compact-Hausdorff "rigidity"

Tags: general-topology

A $(X,\tau)$ Compact-Hausdorff space is a Topology Space that is Hausdorff and compact.

I want to check that there is not topology $\tau_1$ such that $\tau\subset\tau_1$ and Hausdorff but $X$ is compact. That is, I want verify that $X$ is not compact at $\tau_1$.

I thought use $A\in\tau_1\setminus\tau$ and get $A^c$ closed but not compact, but how I get that $A^c$ is not compact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest an alternative argument, illustrating the "rigidity" in a perhaps clearer way. If $(X,\tau)$ is compact Hausdorff, then $\tau$ is the unique topology in its "comparable class" (i.e., which contains or is contained in $\tau$) which is compact Hausdorff.

This is a consequence of the:

**Lemma:** A continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism.

**Proof:** a closed subset of the domain must be compact, so its direct image is compact, and therefore closed (by Hausdorffness of the codomain).

Let $\tau_1$ be a second topology on $X$ which is both compact and Hausdorff. If either inclusion $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau$ or $\tau\subseteq \tau_1$ holds, we will necessarily have that $\tau_1=\tau$, by the lemma applied to either ${\rm Id}_X \colon (X,\tau) \to (X,\tau_1)$ or ${\rm Id}_X\colon (X,\tau_1) \to (X,\tau)$, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

If $A^{c} \in \tau_1$ then $A$ is closed in $(X,\tau_1)$. Hence it is compact in this space. The deifintion of compactness using open  covers shows that $A$ is also compact in $(X,\tau)$. Hence $A$ is closed in $(X,\tau)$. So $A^{c} \in \tau$. This is a contradiction to $\tau \subset \tau_1$.

I have used two facts:

1. Every compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed.
2. Every closed subset of a compact space is compact.